# Y Axis motor is really loud

Tags: anet-a8, motor, nema-17

The Y-axis motor is really loud. The pitch of the sound varies depending the angle of the motor (in some angles the motor is silent, in others it's louder than a fan). I am looking for a solution because this is by far the loudest component of my printer. Is there any settings that could help making this motor quieter? If not, should I replace the motor or the board?

Here is a short clip of the sound of the motor:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sounds are mainly caused by the bed resonating with the stepper motor, and this will vary with the speed of the stepper motor. The best solution is to use "silent" stepper motor drivers (e.g. Trinamic), but you may be able to reduce the noise by:

- Reducing the belt tension as much as possible.
- Changing your print and/or move speeds.
- Fitting a stepper motor damper.
- Fitting TL smoothers (if you have A4988 drivers), although their efficacy is controversial.

I have done all of the above with good results.